# ABS/ESC units used for Active City Stop (Ford)

Tags: ford, part-identification, abs, esp-esc

Does anyone know what ABS/ESC Hydraulic Control Unit (HCU) exactly are being used in Ford cars that feature the Active City Stop? The City Stop needs to be able to initiate brakes electronically and I suspect there may be other pump units used than on models without City Stop.

I am especially interested in smaller Ford models like the Focus Mk3. Is there some online database that could list these parts?

Comment: There are a few models of ABS and ESC on various ford models over the years.  What year are you looking for?   Do you want a simple parts diagram and that's it?

Comment: Yes I only need part number. The focus should be production from 2011 onwards i guess. Is there some parts catalogue?